# The Most Convenient Way to Insert Multiple Histograms within Latex-based Summary Statistics Tables (R)

Tags: r, latex

I was wondering what is the most convenient way to create in R a summary statistics table (in Latex) with one column being graphic presentation of the distribution of that variable.

More specifically, I was looking for something like this:[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to create the document using RMarkdown, or just create the plots in R and then use them in "regular" LaTeX? A similar histogram can be created this way: `par(mar=c(0, 0, 0, 0)); hist(swiss$Fertility, breaks=4, col = "black", main="", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", xlab=NULL, ylab=NULL)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this with the [sparkTable](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sparkTable/index.html) package. That package should give you TeX output.